# add a delay to my NSTimer after i press start game

Tags: ios, delay, nstimer

On my button to start my game i have a few `NSTimers` to make things scroll, i want to add a delay to these timers, not too sure how to though.

any advice?

**Here's the buttons with 1 of the NSTimers**

```
-(IBAction)StartGame:(id)sender{

    StartGame.hidden = YES;



  backgroundMovement = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.06 target:self selector:@selector(backgroundMoving)

                                                   userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

When you call `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...]` the time interval *is* the delay. You will be called back after the time interval you specify.

Alternatively, call `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.

However, note please that there are deep flaws in your proposed architecture. A repeating timer with a `.06` interval is a *terrible* idea, and more than one is an *atrocious* idea. You need to rethink this completely. Consider using real animation, or a display link, or sprite kit. Or something. Anything, really.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to add a delay only once, when starting, you could implement a `- (void)startTimers` method, where you create and start your timers, then do

```
[self performSelector:@selector(startTimers) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
```

in your `IBAction`.

^ Don't copy-paste the performSelector method, as I might have made a typo, since I don't have Xcode open to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Options to do this:

1) call a method with `performSelector` using a delay. In that method you create the NSTimer

```
[self performSelector:@selector(createTimer_backgroundMovement) withObject:nil
                                                                afterDelay:0.1];
```

2) if the delay is dependent of an action you can use this information in a flag and that flag can be used in the `backgroundMoving` method:

```
-(void) backgroundMoving {
    if (!blAction_whichEnablesTimer) {
         return;
    }

    // your backgroundMoving timer code
}
```

3) consider moving views with eg. block animations. Using block animations you can use delay also. Please see doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html